# Randomly sample locations from a large xarray dataset

Tags: python, xarray, sampling, dask

I want to create random sample locations on land (lat/lon), weighted by latitude, from a large xarray dataset. Currently, I am creating the lat/lon pairs from a land-sea-mask with the script below, but I run into memory errors, presumably due to `np.random.choice`. Ideally the code should run lazily and memory-efficiently with dask. Any ideas how?

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# load land-sea mask with lat/lon coordinates
mask = xr.open_dataset('mask.nc', chunks='auto').notnull()

# sample n locations
n = 10000

# transform xarray to dask frame and drop sea values
ds_loc = mask.stack(loc=['lat', 'lon']).to_dask_dataframe()
ds_loc = ds_loc[ds_loc['mask']]

# weight by latitude
weights = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ds_loc.lat))

# randomly sample the locations
loc_s = ds_loc.loc[np.random.choice(ds_loc.index, n, p=weights/np.sum(weights)), ['lat', 'lon']]
loc_s[['lat', 'lon']].to_csv('sample_locations.csv', single_file=True)
```